# How do remove duplicate elements in a ".each do "?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<% @purchased.each do |sale|  %>
Receipt | <%= link_to sale.product.title, pickup_path(sale.guid) %>
<% end %>
```

This results is

```
Receipt | A1 |

Receipt | B1 |

Receipt | A2 |

Receipt | B2 |

Receipt | A1 |

Receipt | B1 |
```

Rather than

```
Receipt | A1 |

Receipt | B1 |

Receipt | A2 |

Receipt | B2 |
```

I was told to use array = array.uniq but I'm unsure how to implement this into the code.

Comment: `@purchased.uniq.each do |sale|` should do the trick, if the array contains real duplicate objects

Comment: Remove the elements *before* iterating the sequence. The fact that there are duplicate entries there *may* indicate a flaw with the underlying data..

Comment: @user2864740 has the right idea. Do this in your controller, not the view. The only data you pass to the view should be the data needed for what you're actually going to display.

Comment: It certainly looks like each of your `sale` items is uniq because it has a `guid`.  If you're concerned about listing a product title multiple times, then you'd need to think about and explain which sale you'd like to link to when displaying only unique titles.  So, if you only want to see product title "A1" one time, which `guid` would you be linking it to with your `pickup_path`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `uniq` such as:

```
<% @purchased.uniq.each do |sale|  %>
```

If it were my codebase, I would prefer to do the `uniq` in the controller, such as:

```
@purchased_uniq = @purchased.uniq
```

Or, if you never need the other @purchased items, then I would do the controller `uniq` using the destructive "!" method, such as:

```
@purchased.uniq!
```

If your @purchased array contains objects (e.g. models) that are different objects, yet some objects associate to the same product, and you want to do the `uniq` based on the product, then you can use a block, such as:

```
@purchased.uniq!{|obj| obj.product }
```

Or by title:

```
@purchased.uniq!{|obj| obj.product.title }
```

Heads up that you want to be careful with this kind of code, because it's the kind of code that can easily cause bugs, such as if a user has multiple purchases for the same product. I suggest writing test code that specifically covers a user having more than one of the same product. Also, you may want to ensure that each product has a unique title, such as by using a database constraint (and optionally a Rails model validates uniqueness).